# Bounties: users with reputation lower than bounty offer

Tags: discussion

Why may users offer a bounty which is much higher than they may afford? Is it fair?
Or bounties may be placed by someone else but the one who asks?

Comment: Do you have a link to the question?  Bounty is taken away from the user's rep when the bounty is offered.  This could reduce the user's rep below the bounty amount. [See also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: @jscott Thanks, this answers the question. Please convert to answer so  I could mark as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a link to the question?  Bounty is taken away from the user's rep when the bounty is offered.  This could reduce the user's rep below the bounty amount.

See also: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).